# Sending XML data using HTTP POST with PHP

Tags: php, xml, http, codeigniter, post

I need to send this XML

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gate>
   <country>NO</country>
   <accessNumber>1900</accessNumber>
   <senderNumber>1900</senderNumber>
   <targetNumber>4792267523</targetNumber>
   <price>0</price>
   <sms>
      <content><![CDATA[This is a test æøå ÆØÅ]]></content>
   </sms>
</gate>
```

to a SMS gateway service. The service listens for HTTP POST requests. The XML must be embedded in the BODY of the POST request.

I'm using PHP and the CodeIgniter framework, but I'm a total PHP n00b, so ideally I'd need a thorough guide, but any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can use cURL library for posting data:
http://www.php.net/curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://websiteURL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "XML=".$xmlcontent."&password=".$password."&etc=etc");
$content=curl_exec($ch);
```

where postfield contains XML you need to send - you will need to name the postfield the API service (Clickatell I guess) expects

Comment: Yeah, I wish... I asked out IT-guy if he could install cURL, but there was no chance he could do it within reasonable time.

Comment: then, see this blog post: http://netevil.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl

Comment: There are also the powerful and very nice pecl_http extension and the various PEAR HTTP_* packages (easier for your IT guy to install).

Answer (score 23):

Another option would be `file_get_contents()`:

```
// $xml_str = your xml
// $url = target url

$post_data = array('xml' => $xml_str);
$stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . "\r\n",
        'content' =>  http_build_query($post_data)));

$context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
```

Comment: yeah, streams have been introduced in PHP 4.3, but are quite hidden for most of the users.

Comment: I am getting error: {Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.nwmls.com/Schemas/General/EverNetQueryXML.xsd) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/phretscl/public_html/xml/pulldata.php on line 42 }

Comment: Hang on isn't the question "How do I send XML" rather than "How do i receive XML and then read it"?