# Raw text SOAP message with PHP

Tags: php, sockets, networking, soap, tcp

I´m trying to do an integration between my own PHP application, and other external software which is 'waiting for' (listening) SOAP messages. But the key question on my situation is that this software which is listening for SOAP messages only accepts RAW contents and has no method which could be called, or Wsdl to be used.

Yes I know... it´s quite strange because with SOAP you usually should send a method request with some parameters, but in this case the only that I have is a URL where I should send with SOAP message that should contain only an string (formatted in a special way which is not a problem), and then this server will return to my PHP application another SOAP message that will contain a string. And that´s all.

Seems that in my case I can not use a PHP SOAP library because I have no method (or function) to call; the only thing that I have is a URL and a string that I should pass like a parameter. I´ve been thinking of using PHP sockets to create a basic SOAP message to that 'strange soap server', but I have no clue about how to do it, or how I woule create with PHP a way to keep my application waiting for the answer comming from that external server.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might be best of by just making the WSDL on your own. It isn't the most trivial thing to do, but it is well documented so you should be able to figure it out.

THere is no need to get the WSDL from the service you're sinding your requests to (it is rather better to have WSDL locally in some cases), so you just initialize the default SOAP client in PHP with that local WSDL, and off you go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nanne. Do you mean that this wsdl would ack like a 'parser' between my php application an the external server?. If so, I guess that I could define a 'ficticious' method (which would be called from my php application), but even in that case I have the same problem. How can I pack a raw string on a SOAP message that shoud be send to a external server if I have no clue about what method is this external server offering?. could the wsdl be defined in such as way to do this? I can´t figure how it could be done. Could you bring me a trail? Thanks again 4 your help.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't quite understand you question maybe. Are you sure it is actual SOAP, and not just plain XML? Because I was thinking that while nothing is defined, you might just be able to figure it out. Example: if I have a method called `method1` that uses parameter `parameter1`, this might translate in some sort of SOAP call going to the URL `example.com/method1` with inside the SOAP call your `parameter1`. So in your case, you might find the method name from the url you are calling, and get your parameters from the SOAP call -> and then you can try and fix yourself a WSDL

Comment: Thank´s again for the answer Nanne. Well I´m aware that this is an extrange situation but yes, I should send a SOAP message to the server but the only that I have is an url like http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port and a string which contains a HL7 message which is in essence a simple string formatted in a special way (which it´s supossed that it will be understod by this external server which is a Rhapshody integration engine).That´s all that I have in order to send a SOAP message to this 'extrange soap server' from my PHP page. I have no XML template or so, no method to be called and no wsdl.

Comment: By the way... the SOAP request should be done throught http protocol that´s because I´m thinking on the possibility to compose a simple SOAP message and send it directly throught tcp using PHP sockets. But I have no idea about how can I handle the response in this situation. Thanks again for your help Nanne.

Comment: Hmm, but you do know what you need to send don't you? You could just compile your own `XML` so it looks like what you want, and then send it manually? Or are you not even sure how your final message should look like? If you do, you could just send it trough `curl` (see for instance this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660983/sending-xml-data-using-http-post-with-php ) ?

Comment: Yes what I need to send it´s a string which I have already prepared an formatted (no prob with that). What I would like to know are in fact two things. what should be the 'minimal soap structure' that my message should contain and how to handle the sending/listeing process with php (curl could be an option for sure).

Comment: well, this is how a soap message looks as you have probably found out yourself. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP#Example_message . I guess you might need to just put your message in the body part and then curl it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Nanne. I´ll do some trials with it.