# How to make my HTTP POST XML request in PHP actually send XML data to my vendor's Server?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm working on some PHP code, that will generate an dynamic XML output that I want to HTTP POST to my Vendor's Server.

My main goal is to get my item stock level synchronized with my Vendor's stock level, and when I POST the request as input, I should get an output back from their server.

I am creating the xml string with DOMDocument, and so far this is no problem, it works fine.

But when I am trying to HTTP POST using the "cUrl" method or the "file_get_contents()" method. The connection is made, but the server response is an error saying "No XML was recieved in HTTP POST".

Im just using the standard code, as explained in this article [Sending XML data using HTTP POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660983/sending-xml-data-using-http-post-with-php) Like many other articles explaning the two methods.

The cUrl Method:

```
$post_data = //the raw xml string or XML file from the DOMDocument.

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://websiteURL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$content=curl_exec($ch);
```

or The file_get_contents() method:

```
$stream_options = array(
'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . "\r\n",
    'content' =>  $post_data));

$context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
```

Both methods gives me a response from the server, that "No XML was recieved in HTTP POST".

If I print_r($post_data); it shows the xml string that i want to send. Like:

```
1. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
2. <pnarequest><customer.nr>some no.</customer_nr><password>some no.</password><Item><vare_nr>some sku no.</vare_nr>
```

**New Info:**

My vendor says they recieve my HTTP POST, but the content in the post is the variable "$post_data" as plain text, not the content inside the variable.

Can someone please help me understanding why the XML data is not being Posted?

Thanks.

**The answer to my question:**
I needed to create the key "xml=" within the post, with my xml ($Post_data) as variable. Also i needed to get the correct user information from my vendor, to put into my xml variable. Now it works! - Thanks to everyone who has helped to comment on this issue.

Comment: Do you need an X-Requested-With header? 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is not `application/xml`

Comment: When I follow their documentation I get: *Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.dcs.dk/xml/xmlOrder/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found* — so something seems to be wrong with the URL and I can't test the code on a working end point.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not encoding the post data and you haven't defined a variable name for the XML field. The HTTP request here, since you're using post, should look like a request sent from a form with a single textarea.

```
<?php

$post_data = rawurlencode($post_data);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'xml=' . $post_data);

?>
```

---

If you need to include more variables with the POST data.

```
<?php

$key = '12345';

$post_data =
    'xml=' . rawurlencode($post_data) .
    '&key=' . rawurlencode($key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

?>
```

---

This is my last example code for you. You're not posting correctly using keys and values. You said you've used the example curl code from the other question, except you aren't, because they **clearly** used keys and values in the accepted answer and you did not. Also, I just checked the form that they have available on the site. The key name should be 'xml', just as I expected and the post should look like a form with a single textarea, just as I expected.

```
<?php

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"...';

$post_data =
    'xml=' . rawurlencode($post_data) .
    '&key=' . rawurlencode($key);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://websiteURL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$content=curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: What? Why? That makes no sense at all. The error says (paraphrasing) "You did not send XML" not "You didn't use Ajax to send this request".

Comment: Now you're converting the data from XML to XML embedded in application/x-www-form-urlencoded data against a key of `XML`, but the documentation the OP linked to said it was expecting XML (i.e. plain XML).

Comment: Why did you recommend the www-form-urlencoded in the second example? Are you trying to send binary data or something? Post data works using keys and values as far as I know and the server will unencode it on its own.

Comment: "Why did you recommend the www-form-urlencoded in the second example?" — I didn't. I pointed out, in a comment, then the OP was describing their data with the wrong content type.

Comment: "Are you trying to send binary data or something?"  — The OP is trying to send XML.

Comment: "Post data works using keys and values as far as I know and the server will unencode it on its own." — POST data uses whatever data format the sender wants. `www-form-urlencoded` is a common format (and is the default for HTML forms) and that uses key/value pairs. The documentation the OP linked to says that they should be sending an XML document.

Comment: Your XML is just a string.

Comment: Since XML is a text based data format, it makes sense to express it as a string. (It is not *my* XML though).

Comment: The documentation says 'you will need to send a HTTP POST with xml as a variable containing the XML'. Try it with lowercase.

Comment: I have switch the application/x-www-form-urlencoded to appliication/xml, with no luck. Still the same respons. - I have also tried to rawurlencode($post_data), and stil gets the same result. - Then i contacted my vendor, and they told me that their server has been down all weekend, cause they was cleaning it. But its stil the same result. And that just makes it even more spooky. why does the server gives me the same result, even when its turned off?

Comment: My vendor says, they only recieve my variable $post_data as text. Any way to post the content of my varible $post_data?

Comment: Jace, please read over the answer I provided. You're not posting correctly.

Comment: I just tried again, using the cUrl with: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'xml=' . $post_data); And now i get a new error, that "User not found 515" - So you're right Brogan, I did not post correctly. One step closer. - I have tried to switch out the variable $post_data with plain xml, but it still gives me the "User not found 515". So i will contact the vendor with this new error. :)

Comment: And it does not work with the 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' header - I will just be sure that i have the right user information before I go further with this question.

Comment: Now it works! It was a combination of the key "xml=" as you said Brogan. And adding the correct user information to the xml. Thanks everyone.!