# How to send an XML file to an external url with POST php

Tags: php, xml, curl

I tried hours with curl function not working. Maybe I have not used it properly.

```
<i>$url = "https://urltosend.com/ext_interface.php?b=update_customer";
  $xmldatafile="JOBS.xml"; 
  function postData($postFileds,$url){ 
            $ch = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST ,1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$postFileds); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER ,0); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,1); 
            $data = curl_exec($ch); 
            curl_close($ch); 
            return $data; 
    } 
 $xmlData = file_get_contents("JOBS.xml"); 
 #echo $xmlData; 
 #$postFileds = 'data='. urlencode($xmlData); 
 $postFileds = 'data='.$xmldatafile; 

 $result = postData($postFileds,"https://urltosend.com/ext_interface.php?b=update_customer"); 
    $result;</i>
```

please help.

Comment: you can use cURL library for posting data: [http://www.php.net/curl](http://www.php.net/curl).

Comment: This may help you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660983/sending-xml-data-using-http-post-with-php).

Comment: I tried to use but it did not help

Comment: Have you heard of guzzle http client?